# Custom Action for installation is executed on uninstall

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have the following WiX XML file:

```
    <Binary Id='IISCustomActionBinary' SourceFile='$(var.Setup.CustomActions.TargetDir)$(var.Setup.CustomActions.TargetName).CA.dll' />
    <CustomAction Id='IISCustomActionInstall' BinaryKey='IISCustomActionBinary' DllEntry='ConfigureIis' Execute='deferred'/>
    <CustomAction Id='IISCustomActionUninstall' BinaryKey='IISCustomActionBinary' DllEntry='UnconfigureIis' Execute='deferred' />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action='IISCustomActionInstall' Before='InstallFinalize'>
            NOT INSTALLED
        </Custom>
        <Custom Action='IISCustomActionUninstall' Before='InstallFinalize'>
            (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")
        </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The "IISCustomActionInstall" custom action executed not only on installs but also when uninstalling. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable that you should be using is `Installed`. `INSTALLED` will be recognized by Windows Installer as a separate user defined variable if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had it written with lower case letters but changed before writing the custom action implementation....